# How to create an app to control employees schedules using javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, frontend

I'm a beginner front-end programmer and I work in civil painting, and my boss asked me to create an app to track employee hours. Every day when we finish our workload, we have to send the hours of the day via whatsapp.I need to create an app for organizing hours, where employees of a company send their hours and they are automatically sent to the boss in an already organized way.

I still don´t have the experience to do it, but it can help me to improve my skills and learn how to think to do it next time

Comment: You are talking about a fully functional app you are going to need backend, database also. I would recommend to use NodeJs as backend and MongoDB as Databse, as you already know javascript, search for like "express tutorial youtube"  (express is a backend node framework). Then you need to search for like "deploy express app youtube" to learn how to make it available online for example

Comment: Other option for the backend/database is Firebase, it's an online database, your front end application can make calls to it and you dont need to build a backend app. Probably firebase will be easier than to learn express + mongoDB

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.